# Callback on cell click in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I want to have a callback function which is fired each time when a cell is clicked. Therefore, i was using the following callback:

```
gridAPI.cellNav.on.navigate($scope, function (newRowCol, oldRowCol)
```

But the problem with it is that i can't fire that function when the same cell second time is clicked. In order to be fired for this, a different cell should be selected. Thus `only-first-click-on-cell` is this.

Is there any callback which i can fire on each click?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, currently there is no any callback for cellClick as far as i see.

The best trick i could write:

```
$scope.cellClicked = function (row, col){
 // do with that row and col what you want
}
```

Cell template on each column:

```
cellTemplate: '<div>
   <div ng-click="grid.appScope.cellClicked(row,col)" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>
      </div>',
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that, it's better to use:

```
rowTemplate: `
    <div
        ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
        ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'"
        class="ui-grid-cell"
        ng-click="grid.appScope.$ctrl.yourFunction(row)"
        ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }"
        role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}"
        ui-grid-cell>
    </div>`,
```

Comment: Can you explain eventually more why it is better?